# How to get Atom to recognize a extension as Ruby

Tags: atom-editor

Currently I am editing .lic files in Atom, they are technically Ruby files that a Ruby based program compiles. They are not registered as Ruby files by Atom because the extension is weird. Is there a way to get Atom to recognize this extension as a ruby file?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you have Ruby-language package in Atom you can maybe try to add the .lic extention name in the config file

Answer (score 0):

You can add a deeper Ruby support in Atom through packages. Hope this help : http://www.rubyguides.com/2017/11/atom-tricks-for-ruby-developers/

:)

Comment: Thank you that is a nice article but I already have Ruby packages installed. I am just trying to get the syntax highlighting working for a Ruby file that has a different extension than a tradition ruby file.